# How to debug Groovy interpreter in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

Groovy interpreter is built atop JVM. I made some Java libraries for JVM and some functions in the library will be called when running groovy scripts. Unfortunately, some error happens.

Therefore, I tried to launch groovy interpreter in the eclipse, so that I can set breakpoints in my code and debug the issue.

Therefore, what I have done is:

1. First, I run the script in linux using `groovy --indy ackermann.groovy 2` and then using `ps` to show the detail parameters. What I got is something like:

   /homes/sxu3/298182/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/p:/homes/sxu3/tools/jars/asmInliner-4.0.1.jar:/homes/sxu3/tools/jars/invoke.jar:/homes/sxu3/tools/jars/asm-all-5.0.3.jar:/homes/sxu3/tools/jars/common-4.0.1.jar:/homes/sxu3/tools/jars/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar:/homes/sxu3/tools/jars/logback-core-1.1.3.jar:/homes/sxu3/tools/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/homes/sxu3/tools/jars/conf/ -classpath /homes/sxu3/bin/groovy-2.4.8/lib/groovy-2.4.8.jar -Dscript.name=/homes/sxu3/bin/groovy-2.4.8/bin/groovy -Dprogram.name=groovy -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/homes/sxu3/bin/groovy-2.4.8/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Dgroovy.home=/homes/sxu3/bin/groovy-2.4.8 -Dtools.jar=/homes/sxu3/298182/lib/tools.jar org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --main groovy.ui.GroovyMain --conf /homes/sxu3/bin/groovy-2.4.8/conf/groovy-starter.conf --classpath . --indy ackermann.groovy 2
2. In eclipse, I create a `run configuration` > `Java application` > new. 
   The main class is: 
   `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter`

and the VM Arguments:

```
-Dscript.name=Y:\bin\groovy-2.4.8\bin\groovy -Dprogram.name=groovy -Dgroovy.starter.conf=Y:\bin\groovy-2.4.8\conf\groovy-starter.conf -Dgroovy.home=y:\bin\groovy-2.4.8 -Dtools.jar=Y:\298182\lib\tools.jar --main groovy.ui.GroovyMain --conf Y:\bin\groovy-2.4.8\conf\groovy-starter.conf -classpath .   --indy
```

and the "Program Arguments": 
`Y:\bin\indy-benchmark-suite_orig\programs\groovy\ackermann.groovy 300`

This is shown as in the [image: Screenshot]

3 Add my libraries to the VM bootstrap and classpath.

After clicking the `Run` in the `debug configuration`, I got errors below:

`JVMJ9VM007E Command-line option unrecognised: --main`

The trick is at groovy's groovy.sh script, which launches a Java process. Therefore, I am looking whether some people can help solve it. Also how interpreter developers debug during development.

Comment: Does this help?
[How to debug Groovy code via the remote Java application debugging in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568957/how-to-debug-groovy-code-via-the-remote-java-application-debugging-in-eclipse)